# Fundamental rule for probability calculus for A, B | C

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For 2 events, it holds that $P(A, B) = P(A | B) * P(B)$. A lot of texts ([for example this one](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs9417ml/Bayes/Pages/Joint_Probability.html)) say that this rule can be extended for $P(A, B | C)$. It then holds that $P(A, B | C) = P(A | B, C) * P(B | C)$.

But when applying the first rule for 2 with $A = A$ and $B = B | C$, I find $P(A, B | C) = P(A | B | C) * P(B | C)$? I cannot find anywhere that $P(A | B| C)$ is equal to $P(A | B, C)$? How do these relate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(A, B| C)$ means $P((A\land B)|C)$, not (as you write) $P(A\land (B|C))$. The second expression, actually, makes no sense. $B|C$ is not an event.

Answer (score 0):

As 5xum said in his reply, P(A,B|C) means P((A∧B)|C). Said in words, P(A,B|C) means the probability of A and B given C, NOT the probability of A with B given by C.

Knowing this, we apply the equation P(A,B)=P(A|B)∗P(B),

$P(A,B|C) = \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(A|B,C) P(B,C)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(A|B,C) P(B|C) P(C)}{P(C)} = P(A|B,C) P(B|C)$,

giving the desired result.